# Как начать проигрывание спарсеной музыки\ куда она скачивается

Tags: python-3.x, request

Есть ссылка на скачивание песни: 
https://cdndl.zaycev.net/123720/9793248/mokhito_-_ruki_proch_%28zaycev.net%29.mp3?ext.page=default

В моем понимании данный запрос её скачивает.

```
requests.get("https://cdndl.zaycev.net/123720/9793248/mokhito_-_ruki_proch_%28zaycev.net%29.mp3?ext.page=default")
```

Вопрос: куда он её скачивает ?

Comment: Эта функция возвращает объект, внутри которого лежит скачанное содержимое. Вы этот объект никак не использовали, поэтому всё скачанное уничтожается сразу после скачивания за ненадобностью.

Comment: В продолжение того что сказал  andreymal объект нужно сохранить

Comment: типа так with open("my_song.mp3", "rb") as file: file.write(ссылка на объект) а также к методу get добавить через точку content

Answer (score 0):

**Только для Windows**

[Ссылка на pybass.whl](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rK0238fWbzChtZJTSUZYKKde3IYFxqhg)

Установка через pip

*Как то захотел написать плеер для потокового воспроизведения музыки*

*На Python не нашёл модуль и решил сделать сам*

*Пример использования:*

```
from pybass import PlaySound
player = PlaySound()
player.loadUrl("http://ic5.101.ru:8000/a43?userid=0&setst=s4o73u77vc95mh6pa16epoligs&token=XwG5CJl3kAWDVuKTtr4B2F7EPRMxNU81")
player.play()
```